# React router dom: Route and Router not working at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am fairly new to react and trying to make a redirect using react-router-dom I did everything as the documentation but my code doesn't seem to work. I get an error regarding no element found which I don't understand what is causing it. Also, I am just trying to reach the page using the address bar and not any button or link for now.

**Error**

```
Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.
```

*Same error for /register*

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Register from "./components/Register";

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Routes>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        HELLO WORLD
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

**Register.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Register(){
    const history = useNavigate();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
          email: '',
          password: '',
      });

      const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      updateFormData({
              ...formData,
              // Trimming any whitespace
              [event.target.name]: event.target.value.trim(),
          });
    }

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event.target.email.value);
      console.log(event.target.password.value);
    }

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>
            Email: 
            <input type="text" value={formData.email} name="email" onChange={handleChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Password: 
            <input type="text" value={formData.password} name="password" onChange={handleChange}/>
          </label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not rendering the route components correctly. They should be rendered as JSX, not a reference to the component, on the `element` prop. This is a breaking change between versions 5 and 6 of `react-router-dom`. Note also that `Route` components also no longer take an `exact` prop, they are now *always* exactly matched.

```
ReactDOM.render( 
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
      </Routes>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

can you slightly modify your `index.js` and try once again:

**react-router-dom@5**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {
    Switch,
    Route,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "./components/Register";

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**react-router-dom@6**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {
    Route,
    Routes,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Register from "./components/Register";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
            </Routes>
            <App />
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

This should work.

Comment: "switch is not exported" error

Comment: @RevTpark which version of react-router-dom you're using?

Comment: @PradipDhakal If `Switch` isn't exported then OP is using v6.x.

Comment: its the latest one ig

Comment: I've written down for both version 5 and 6. You can check it out.

Comment: v5 users won't see this specific error message, BTW 

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import LoginForm from "./authentication/LoginForm";
import RegisterForm from "./authentication/RegisterForm";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LoginForm />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterForm />} />
        </Routes>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

/*This works for me*/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

initially it was like this:

```
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
```

but now change to:

```
    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
```

read more about react routes v6 => { https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-react-router-version-6/ }